# The Status of SEO with languages as Angular and React?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, reactjs, seo

I'm thinking of using Angular or React for a new web project but the SEO are an important part. From what I have read there are ways to solve it but it always results in keeping two page version alive or using an external service that renders the pages.

This sounds like bad options to me?

I have also read some unclear info about that search engines now can read javascript webpages with for example angular or react?

Could someone clarify this for me? Will SEO be as good with Angular as if I was using, for example, ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't speak for Angular but React.js is perfect for SEO. The reason is that every state of your application can be fully rendered server side. 
So this is not like your traditional ajax page where you have your base view and then do some ajax/javascript stuff to go to the next state.

Comment: Sounds great but how does it really work? Do I have to store static pages or is it rendered on demand for the spiders? Do I have to do some extra work to get this going and get it to be updated? Could ASP.NET MVC work with React.js?